# Bootstrap 'collapsed' class not appearing on DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an accordion menu using Bootstrap's Collapse functionality, and I tried to style it based on the CSS classes Bootstrap uses to show and hide the collapsible element.

My problem is that when the document is fully loaded, the `collapsed` class is not loaded on the collapsed elements, while they appear collapsed. So my page renders with it's 'open' styling, while every collapsible element is collapsed like it should be. After the first couple of clicks, the `collapsed` class is present and the styling works as it should.

Forcing the `collapsed` class onto each element post DOM load for one is a messy way to solve the problem, but the styling still shows up for a second before changing.

To illustrate, this should be happening:

**Collapsed State[image: Collapsed State]**

**Uncollapsed State**[image: Uncollapsed State]

But instead, on load, I'm getting this as the `collapsed` classes simply aren't present:
[image: What actually happens on load]

Any ideas what can be done about this?

**Edit:** Code Inclusion (ignore the Razor snippets)

```
<button class="category-select" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-@i">@fieldset.GetValue("title")</button>
    <div id="collapsible-@i" class="collapse">
        <div class="category-inner">
            @Html.Raw(@fieldset.GetValue("innerText"))
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: pls share your code here

Comment: Sounds like $( document ).ready() is missing to run the code upon document load

Comment: Where would that be though? This is using unedited Bootstrap v3.3.5

Comment: Tested as not working in latest BS build (3.3.7) as well

Answer (score 2):

Just realised what I did wrong based on the styles that are present. What I should have done is added the `collapsed` class to the html myself.

The code should in fact look like this:

```
<button class="category-select collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-@i">@fieldset.GetValue("title")</button>
<div id="collapsible-@i" class="collapse">
    <div class="category-inner">
        @Html.Raw(@fieldset.GetValue("innerText"))
    </div>
</div>
```

Correct styles are then applied on load, ready for `collapsed` to be removed on click.

**Very** silly mistake.